# Trouble with header files when mixing Objective-C and C++

Tags: header-files, objective-c++

In my iOS app I have a mixture of .h/.m files for pure Objective-C classes and .h/.mm files for classes consisting of an Objective-C and C++ mixture. Everything works fine when I put something like:

```
#include <vector>
using namespace std;
```

at the top of a `.mm` file. However when I move the above `#include` to a `.h` file (that has an associated .mm file) I receive the error message:

```
'vector' file not found
```

I tried changing the header's file extension to `.hpp` but that results in the same error message. **How can I fix this?**

Comment: Make all of your objective-c files that include that header `.mm`s.

Comment: @RichardJ.RossIII Ok I did this. What to do about the other .h files that include the header in question? Perhaps all .m files in the project should just be .mm?

Comment: If you're dropping C++ everywhere like this, then yes, it is mandatory that everything included be `mm` files.

Comment: @SundayMonday: You should only rarely include headers in other headers. Also, if you use some C++ thing that is only used in one file, then it shouldn't be in a header.